# #INVALID_APP_ID@auth_handlers_facebook.getIdByToken

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook, facebook-login

When I try to login with facebook token and fb id in tinder  (using objective c / swift code both ) I am getting this error.

App is created in fb dev portal and app id is configured with in the app, 
I am getting token when I try to login with facebook. Bu that id shows like an invalid id. Why i am facing this issue. Kindly help me anyone. I could nt find even a single discussion regarding this issue. I cannot contact to tinder / facebook . kindly help me if anyone done this integration.

I am following this documentation for authentication.
https://github.com/fbessez/Tinder

API used for Auth  > https://api.gotinder.com/auth

Body of my request and response ( in postman)

```
{
  "facebook_token": "EAAGm0PX4ZCpsBAH4C0wwXkYCqWvVFKEI4N0ZBzA2CVsmUl88uze2ZAdZCEUqyTMXiXRh8ngnSH25oEbtXUhASrCpnkFEhjbeiVRDxoeo6LWnQs8ymRwMBZBQHcSs5MdCBkIZAW3q0DBs2GEo5HsidWw1D2OhYqoQNWQIU3MaJU2cRcccccccQrIp1WMosjTviZCnyXkS7pVOwXbLoyhpnJv1mqHU0yV08Ovp0tW39SvZBgZDZD",
  "facebook_id": "5788960392353_ _"
}
```

**Headers**

```
Content-type:application/json
User-agent:Tinder/7.5.3 (iPhone; iOS 10.3.2; Scale/2.00)
```

My response is like this from tinder.

```
 {
"code": 401,
"error": "Invalid App ID 3029145736496_ _#INVALID_APP_ID@auth_handlers_facebook.getIdByToken}",
"error_no": 87401
}
```

Please help me on this ,I'm not understanding where i'm doing wrong, so anyone please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Show example of your code (use placeholders for user-specific data)

Comment: show your code what have you tried then nobody downvotes :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you propably won't get answer with information you provided (you may have a typo in your code or have missed something in docs)

Comment: As per ur suggestion i have added the flow of my code. Hope this wll be fine for getting answer.

Comment: I am having the same problem... seems it try to connect with the App ID as it should take the User ID provided instead... don't understand why yet